# Active Admin Namespaced Model Form

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I am having issues with AA (1.0.0pre) and Rails 4.1.3.  I have a namespaced model:

```
Surveyor::Survey
```

for which I want an admin form for. But the name attributes of the inputs does not reflect the namespacing of the attributes

```
<input id="survey_name" maxlength="255" name="survey[name]" type="text">
```

instead of

```
<input id="surveyor_survey_name" maxlength="255" name="surveyor_survey[name]" type="text">
```

Also this is working fine in Rails 3.2.x and AA .6.  Lastly when inspecting the form_builder element i found this:

```
#<ActiveAdmin::Resource::Name:0x0000010a9d86a8
            @collection="surveyor_surveys",
            @element="surveyor_survey",
            @human="Surveyor survey",
            @i18n_key=:surveyor_survey,
            @klass=Surveyor::Survey(id: integer, name: string, description: text, attempts_number: integer, finished: boolean, active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime),
            @name="SurveyorSurvey",
            @param_key="surveyor_survey",
            @plural="surveyor_surveys",
            @route_key="surveyor_surveys",
            @singular="surveyor_survey",
            @singular_route_key="surveyor_survey">=>#<ActiveAdmin::Resource:0x0000010a9d8f90 ...>
```

Which makes it seem like it knows the correct namespacing but its not displaying on the form inputs for some reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: It might be due to formtastic and its method of building forms. What is it you're working to accomplish where the form fields need a specific namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its as simple as:

```
form :as => 'surveyor_survey'
```